# How to dynamically change images and fonts in Flutter web application?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I would like to dynamically change the background image and buttons colors when I click on a button. There are 3 different buttons, each one corresponds to one website theme (set of a background image and button color).
The problem is when I click on the button to change the website theme nothing happens. Website theme changes only when I change website scale ('ctrl' + '+/-').

```
//HERE IS MY CODE THAT STANDS FOR THE BUTTON WIDGET

class ButtonWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final List listOfThemes;
  final int itemIndex;
  ButtonWidget(this.listOfThemes, this.itemIndex);

  @override
  _ButtonWidgetState createState() => _ButtonWidgetState();
}

class _ButtonWidgetState extends State<ButtonWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 170,
      height: 50,
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
//themesList is a list of objects, each object from the list represents one theme (contains theme images, fonts, colors etc)
          backgroundPath = themesList[widget.itemIndex].backgroundImage;
          changedTextColor = themesList[widget.itemIndex].textColor;
          changedButtonColor = themesList[widget.itemIndex].buttonColor;
          changedButtonTextColor = themesList[widget.itemIndex].buttonTextColor;
          String name = themesList[widget.itemIndex].name;
          print(name);
          });
        },
        color: themesList[widget.itemIndex].buttonColor,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              themesList[widget.itemIndex].name,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: themesList[widget.itemIndex].textColor,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Can you advise me on how to change the website content (images, colors, fonts) on button click without a need to do any additional actions for the user?

Check screens of the website:

[before changing scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kjund.jpg)

[after changing website scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1Ic3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source code you have a property called `itemIndex`

This property does not change anywhere. You are invoking the onPressed function and changing the properties below based on a value that does not change. You need to make sure that when pressing on any of the buttons that change the themes, that they will in turn change the value of this common index. My suggestion is to use a static index that can easily be shared between the widgets.

You can also do this, to allow the themes to toggle between each other, assuming you have 3 themes available (also never do any kind of work inside the SetState(). This function is only to be used for rebuilding the widget, which can block the thread:

```
  if(widget.itemIndex < 2){
     widget.itemIndex++;
  }
  else {
     widget.itemIndex = 0;
  }

  backgroundPath = themesList[widget.itemIndex].backgroundImage;
  changedTextColor = themesList[widget.itemIndex].textColor;
  changedButtonColor = themesList[widget.itemIndex].buttonColor;
  changedButtonTextColor = themesList[widget.itemIndex].buttonTextColor;
  String name = themesList[widget.itemIndex].name;
  print(name);
                
  setState(() {}); //Rebuild the widget
```